# How do I display the answer of my PHP and HTML program?

Tags: php, html, web

I have my code for my PHP:

```
 <?php
$num1= $_REQUEST["number1"];
$num2= $_REQUEST["number2"];
$arithmetic = $_POST['arithmetic'];

switch ($arithmetic) {
case "addition":
  $answer = $num1+$num2;
  echo "<p>$num1 added with $num2 is " . number_format($answer,2) . "</p>";
  break;

case "subtraction":
  $answer = $num1-$num2;
  echo "<p>$num2 subtracted from $num1 is " . number_format($answer,2) .     "</p>";
  break;

case "multiplication":
  $answer = $num1*$num2;
  echo "<p>$num1 multiplied by $num2 is " . number_format($answer,2) . "</p>";
  break;

case "division":
  $answer = $num1/$num2;
  echo "<p>$num1 divided by $num2 is " . number_format($answer,2) . "</p>";
  break;

case "modulus":
  $answer = $num1%$num2;
  echo "<p>The remainder of $num1 divided by $num2 is " . number_format($answer,2) . "</p>";
  break;
}
?>

<br>
 <form action="calcD.html" target="iframeMain">
   <input type="submit" value="go back">
 </form>

 <?php
   echo "<HR>";
   highlight_file("calcD.php");
 ?>
```

and my code for my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scada:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Dropdown Calculator</h2>
  <form action="calcD.php" method="POST" target="iframeMain" autocomplete="off">
    <p>Number 1:<input type="text" name="number1"></p>
    <p>Number 2:<input type="text" name="number2"></p>
    <h3>Type of Arithmetic</h3>
    <select name="arithmetic">
    <option name="addition">Addition</option>
    <option name="subtraction">Subtraction</option>
    <option name="multiplication">Multiplication</option>
    <option name="division">Division</option>
    <option name="modulus">Modulus</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="compute" value="Compute">
  </form>
  <a href="assignment3.html" target="iframeMain">Back to Menu</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to use my programs, the answer doesn't display. I have check on multiple sites and there are no errors with my HTML nor my PHP but my answer is not displaying. I have even tried using If and Elseif statements for each program. Is there a link I am missing for them?

EDIT: I need to use a `switch (strtolower($arithmetic))` instead of the standard switch to allow it to display.

Comment: I see no "selected": http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: I added this and still no luck with displaying my answers.

Comment: then update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `switch (strtolower($arithmetic))`. you have up case in your arithmetic post value...

Comment: AHH THIS WAS IT! Thank you!

Comment: This is only because you have incorrectly used `name` instead of `value`, as I have said in my answer. An option with no value will use the text as the value instead (note that the name attribute does absolutely nothing). **If you had fixed this as I described, the code would work correctly!**

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your options. You have

`<option name="subtraction">Subtraction</option>`

They should have values, not names:

`<option value="subtraction">Subtraction</option>`

Comment: I also tried this! When I was sifting through numerous sites explaining switches, I was told not to use value and use name. Nevertheless, this did not work.

Comment: `name` is not a valid attribute for options. The site that suggested you use it is mistaken. As for your code, I have tested it locally and it works as intended with the change above.... `2 added with 2 is 4.00`

Comment: Then it must be my CSS or how the page is displayed in my iframe because when I click the compute button, nothing but the button to go back is displayed.

Comment: In your switch, add a default condition, and see if you still get no output.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$num1= $_POST["number1"];
$num2= $_POST["number2"];
```

Comment: I changed my code; Still did not work, and yet still no errors. Thanks for posting!